# Deploying Bokeh server on EMR

Tags: python, bokeh, amazon-emr

Am trying to deploy my Bokeh application on EMR cluster. But am getting stopped with the message 'HTTP request sent : waiting for response.'

Am using below command to deploy my bokeh application on EMR
bokeh serve --show --allow-websocket-original=:5006 app.py

Port is 5006 is opened on the cluster

when i run this command, bokeh server is stating on port 5006 for the given app, created process id. But going to waiting stage with the message 'HTTP request sent : waiting for response' long time. 
Am expecting my application should be launched in the browser available (firefox). Please let me know what to do here. Or provide me steps if am not following correctly.

Comment: Issue is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is solved now. Solution is just by removing 'show' command in while deploying 'bokeh serve'